# Webapp2 get_by_auth_token using wrong entity key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, webapp2

With webapp2, when creating a new user it just does a simple entity.put() without setting a custom entity key using the auth_id. However if you try to retrieve a user by auth token it assumes there's an entity for (Kind, auth_id) which comes up empty since its key is set to (Kind, id). Am I missing something?  Why is that key assumed in get_by_auth_token to be Kind, auth_id?
create_user does this:

```
ok, existing = cls.unique_model.create_multi(k for k, v in uniques)
    if ok:
    user.put()
```

but get_by_auth_token does this:

```
token_key = cls.token_model.get_key(user_id, 'auth', token)
user_key = model.Key(cls, user_id)
valid_token, user = model.get_multi([token_key, user_key])
```

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html#User.get_by_auth_token

Seems like this isn't getting much activity but just in case someone runs across this bug.

create_user is not setting the key which defaults to setting an id.  I extended the user model and overrode the create_user class method to set an entity key to the auth_id.  You'll need to override add_auth_id to update the key to the new auth_id.

```
    user_values['auth_ids'] = [auth_id]
    user_key = model.Key(cls, auth_id)
    user = cls(key=user_key, **user_values)
```

Comment: I'd upvote this twice if I could, thanks for asking the question and also finding the answer.  This has been wrecking my head!!!!!!  Is there any chance you could share a little more of your create_user method so that I know what to include in mine??

Answer (score 0):

Since the param named `'user_id'` instead of `'auth_id'`, i think it's designed on purpose.  It suggest you to use auto generated id as part of token.

The benefit of such design is that simple `model.Key(cls, id)` could be faster, and it does not contain any sensitive information (such as user email) within token.

So, In both `create_auth_token(user_id)` and `get_by_auth_token(user_id)`, pass `user_id = user.key.id()`  might be a less hacky way to go.